# Synchronize android contacts with my own rest api

Tags: android, rest, synchronization, carddav

I'd like to periodically update contacts on my android phone with my own server(REST based service). Is it ok to create simple service to run in background and communicate with my REST to get updates from server or maybe I should transfer contacts to ex. carddav and use existing android apps to download them?